# DataTables Controller gets data from multiple sources, how to handle one of those sources being unavailable

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, datatables

A data table lists all systems that are currently running across four separate servers. Sometimes one (or more) of these servers are unavailable for a variety of reasons. However, when populating this data table, it seems that if one of these servers are down or the source can't be reached, the table will fail to populate at all and throw an exception.

I've cut out some of the superfluous code below, including only the try/catch block that seems to be of importance.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetSystemList(DataTableAjaxPostModel model)
{
    try
        {
            var result = (await Api.GetSystems("NetworkOne")).Select(w => new SystemModel(w, db)).Select(tr => new SystemListDisplay
            {
                SystemName = tr.SystemName,
                SystemGid = tr.GuardianId,
                SystemGroup = db.Groups.Find(tr.GroupId)?GroupName ?? "Unknown",
                Server = "NetworkOne"
            }).ToArray();

            Array.Resize(ref result, result.Length + dresult.Length);
            int i = 1;
            foreach (var system in dresult)
            {
                result[result.Length - i] = system;
                i++;
            }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
           using (var logger = new GrayLogUdpClient())
           {
                 logger.Send(ex);
           }
      }
}
```

This try/catch block is repeated for each of the servers.

This project pre-dates me by quite a bit so I'm trying to piece it together (as it is part of a much larger MVC project). At one point there only was one server and as each subsequent one was added, the try/catch block was simply replicated.

The issue appears to be that the task to retrieve a given system list from a server runs indefinitely (as per checking the developer console in Chrome when troubleshooting).

```
internal static async Task<Network[]> GetSystems(string server, bool expandNodes = true)
        {
            Network[] Networks = await GetValueOrNull<Network[]>($"{server}/network/find/device/%25?expandNodes={expandNodes}&array=true", true);

            return Networks;
        }
```

This is the API call that seems to be "stalling" indefinitely if the server is down or unavailable. Is it possible to initiate a "timeout" that will continue to the next try/catch block if the server cannot be reached?

Comment: `The issue appears to be that the task to retrieve a given system list from a server runs indefinitely` -- So it sounds like the real problem is the API call (Api.GetSystems) is stalling?

Comment: I'll edit to include the API call in my original question. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But again (and tell me if I'm wrong) it sounds like the actual problem is that the API call is taking a long time to finish. Is that correct? Can you test the API call in Postman to see if it works correctly outside of your code?

Comment: You may need to make the connection time longer.  Many people have issue with not finding server and increasing the connection time seems to solve issues.